# Type error The "original" argument must be of type Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, lighthouse

Getting above error while trying to run the below code
added all the dependencies, tried to define the function in all possible ways, still the same issue

```
const fs = require('fs');
const lighthouse = require('lighthouse');
const chromeLauncher = require('chrome-launcher');

(async () => {
  const chrome = await chromeLauncher.launch({chromeFlags: ['--headless']});
  const options = {logLevel: 'info', output: 'html', onlyCategories: ['performance'], port: chrome.port};
  const runnerResult = await lighthouse('https://example.com', options);

  // `.report` is the HTML report as a string
  const reportHtml = runnerResult.report;
  fs.writeFileSync('lhreport.html', reportHtml);

  // `.lhr` is the Lighthouse Result as a JS object
  console.log('Report is done for', runnerResult.lhr.finalUrl);
  console.log('Performance score was', runnerResult.lhr.categories.performance.score * 100);

  await chrome.kill();
})();
```

here are the dependencies

[image]

below is the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "react-class-components",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "keywords": [],
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "chrome-launcher": "0.14.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "lighthouse": "8.0.0",
    "react": "16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "3.3.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Which versions of lighthouse and chrome-launcher are installed?

Comment: lighthouse - 8.0.0
chrome-launcher - 0.14.0

Comment: Could you add the exact error message along with the whole stack AND add package.json you use to the post, along with node version? The error you've shown is thrown by internal Node module it seems, and can be a symptom of different issues.

Comment: trying it one code sandbox feeling there are version issues in my local system

Comment: That's weird to see `fs` package among the list of dependencies. What's `node -v` output? Can you uninstall that one?

Comment: removed fs from dependencies, node version is 10.20.1 by default in code sandbox

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234495/discussion-between-yvdevy-and-raina77ow).